# Determinant of a matrix after changes

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant

If $\det \begin{pmatrix}a&1&d\\ b&1&e\\ c&1&f\end{pmatrix}=1$ and $\det \begin{pmatrix}a&1&d\\ b&2&e\\ c&3&f\end{pmatrix}=1$, what is $\det \begin{pmatrix}a&-4&d\\ b&-5&e\\ c&-6&f\end{pmatrix}$?

So I am aware about all the different operations and what changes they bring to the value of the determinant, but I am not exactly sure which one of them is being applied here. There is no constant multiplication or an addition or subtraction by a row. I have tried to add and subtract various multiples of the matrices from each other as well but not to any avail. I believe I am just not spotting something.

Any help?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

By the multilinearity of determinant,
$$\begin{aligned}
& \begin{vmatrix}a&-4&d\\ b&-5&e\\ c&-6&f\end{vmatrix} \\
&= \begin{vmatrix}a&-1&d\\ b&-2&e\\ c&-3&f\end{vmatrix}+\begin{vmatrix}a&-3&d\\ b&-3&e\\ c&-3&f\end{vmatrix} \\ 
&= -\begin{vmatrix}a&1&d\\ b&2&e\\ c&3&f\end{vmatrix}-3\begin{vmatrix}a&1&d\\ b&1&e\\ c&1&f\end{vmatrix} \\ 
&= -1 -3(1) =-4.
\end{aligned}
$$

Comment: Wow...Well spotted...

Comment: *bangs head against wall*